# Ionic 4 PWA - Capacitor and Camera plugin weird behavyour

Tags: plugins, camera, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I am trying to take pictures from an Ionic 4 PWA application.
I read this docs from Ionic team and implemented all the proposed steps... (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/guides/ionic-framework-app/)
The (weird) result can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

When the camera prompt seen in this picture is shown, Chrome console prints out an object called MediaStreamTrack with this values:
kind: "video"
id: "6250dfa4-d9aa-4a87-ab9f-ae085f929c3f"
label: "screen-capture-recorder"
enabled: true
muted: false
onmute: null
onunmute: null
readyState: "live"
onended: null
contentHint: ""
**proto**: MediaStreamTrack

When I click in the button to take picture, I can see this message:

```
Unable to take photo! DOMException: setOptions failed - pwa-camera.entry.js:259
```

I have used the sample code the Ionic team presented in the docs:

```
export class Tab2Page {
    photo: SafeResourceUrl;

    constructor(
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

    async takePicture() {
        const image = await Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
            quality: 100,
            allowEditing: false,
            resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
            source: CameraSource.Camera
        });

        this.photo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image && (image.dataUrl));
    }

}
```

And...

```
<ion-content>
    <img [src]="photo">

    <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button (click)="takePicture()">
            <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

I changed everything in this code trying to figure out what is going wrong, but nothing seem to fix this behavyour.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
My Chrome version is 79.0.3945.79

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage it friend? i have "no camera found" error